# Can organisms grow on acetic acid?

Tags: microbiology, metabolism

Can organisms grow on acetic acid and water (with <1%, all inorganic, impurities), i.e. using acetic acid as a carbon / energy source?

If so which concentration of water would it start at? (assuming it doesn't happen without water)

Comment: Welcome Hans. We're expected to show our own research into a topic when asking. Please [edit] to tell us what you searched, found and where you got stuck. Also, please take our [tour] and refer to the [help] for guidance. Acetic acid (ethanol oxide) is already pretty stable as it's the metabolic product of several processes, would you perhaps be referring to an extreme environment, perhaps a fictional one? Then [worldbuilding.se] might help there.